# How is CC3000 placed in Simple Configuration mode?

Tags: pcb, wifi, texas-instruments, configuration

I've ordered a CC3000MODR and soldered it to a [simple breakout board](https://github.com/kuym/TICC3000Breakout). In the [First Time Configuration](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3000_First_Time_Configuration) it mentions a Simple Configuration mode:

> The CC3000 is placed in Simple Configuration mode and begins looking
> for beacons or probes
> ...
>
> In order to perform the first time config procedure, the CC3000 must
> enter that mode. In this section it is assumed that the first-time
> configuration process can be triggered externally on the CC3000
> device. For example, a user may press a button to initiate the
> process.

Since the document assumes that the first-time configuration process can be triggered, I can't seem to find how to put the CC3000 into the Simple Configuration mode. Can anyone explain to me how this is accomplished, given that I have a simple breakout board?